# Count if a value is between two dates

Tags: count, powerbi-desktop

I have a column that shows the date a task was completed. Some rows are blank, which means the task is still being worked on (and can be disregarded)

[image]

I am trying to write a measure that counts the number of rows which are between a start date and an end date. For example, in the table, there are three rows which are 10-aug-2022. I tried the following

```
Closed Tickets = COUNT(datesbetween(Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED],DATE(2022,07,09),DATE(2022,08,11)))
```

I get the error that The COUNT function only accepts a column reference as an argument. I need the number 3 returned.

I think I need to use a different function to count if (since I want to specify a particular date in the expression and not reference another column). I was working on the following, but I cant get the right syntax

```
Closed Tickets = calculate(COUNT(Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED],FILTER(Issues,Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED]>=DATE(2002,08,9)&&Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED]<=DATE(2002,08,11)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

edit - I also tried the following

Closed Tickets = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Issues,Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED]>=DATE(2022,8,11)&&Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED]<=DATE(2022,8,11)))

But Im getting  in my table when expect 12

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Closed Tickets (JULY) = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Issues,Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED]>=DATE(2022,7,15)&&Issues[ISSUE_RESOLVED]<=DATE(2022,8,15)))